# Vernacular Targum in Schul

Tags: halacha, translation, torah-reading, torah-service, language

In Teimani and Kurdish batei knesset, the minhag is, as far as I'm aware, to read a targum after each pasuk. Assuming that a schul wishes to adopt the kriat hatargum, would it be acceptable to adopt a targum in the vernacular of the community? What issues would be involved?

As always, for a practical ruling, [CYLOR](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146/why-is-it-necessary-to-ask-a-rabbi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so because the Gemara in Megillah (3a?) names specific authorized Targumim for Chumash and Navi.

Comment: Yitzchak, please summarise the discussion on this in your answer.